# C# Method Calculate

Tags: c#, methods

I am trying to calculate the perimeter of a circle using method
for some reason I get an error at:

```
   //double p = 2 * Math.PI * r;
```

I am new to using method please help and show me what I did wrong.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        double perimeter;
        Console.Write("Enter Perimeter: ");
        double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out perimeter);
        double per = PerimeterOfCircle(perimeter);
        Console.WriteLine("\nPerimeter of Circle = {0}",
            per.ToString("F3"));


        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static double PerimeterOfCircle(double p)
    {
        double p = 2 * Math.PI * r;
        return p;
    }
```

Comment: `double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out perimeter);` Don't do this, your mixing user input, parsing, and ignoring the return value of the function. Put the read on a seperate line, and abort early if the try parse fails.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like you have the parameter named incorrectly.  Change it to `r`:

```
static double PerimeterOfCircle(double r)   // <-- changed from p to r here
{
    double p = 2 * Math.PI * r;
    return p;
}
```

Also you can embed the format string within `WriteLine`:

```
Console.WriteLine("\nPerimeter of Circle = {0:F3}", per);
```

Comment: Oh I see, lol that little mistakes bothered me the whole time I can't believe I didn't see it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simple: You did not provide a value for `r`. The code does not even compile.